# Deserialize Web Api OData response

Tags: c#, json, linq, serialization, odata

I have an Entity Framework object returned by OData V4 controller.
I return an IQueryable and if I call the OData endpoint without any OData clause I can succesfully do this:

```
var content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IQueryable<Person>>();
```

And the response in JSON is the following:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://xxx:8082/odata/$metadata#Persons","value":[
    {
      "Id":"291b9f1c-2587-4a35-993e-00033a81f6d5",
      "Active":true,
      "Alert":"Some alerts for the Person",
      "Comments":"Some comments for the Person"
    }
  ]
}
```

But as soon as I start to play with OData, for example by using $expand on a Complex property I get the following exception:

***Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[xxx.Person]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.***

And the response is the following:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://aqavnext01:8082/odata/$metadata#Persons","value":[
    {
      "Id":"291b9f1c-2587-4a35-993e-00033a81f6d5",
      "Active":true,
      "Alert":"Some alerts for the Person",
      "Comments":"Some comments for the Person",
      "Party":{
        "Id":"291b9f1c-2587-4a35-993e-00033a81f6d5"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am deserializing using the same object returned by my Web Api so I don't understand why it fails.
Same issue when I apply $select.

Comment: Can you provide more code like the controller and data model?  And maybe not directly related to your question, $expand is for navigation property but not complex type.

Comment: I just send back a DbContext set. The problem is the deserialization in C#, in Javascript we have no problems at all.

return dbContext.Set<Person>()

Answer (score 8):

Try deserialize the content like this:

```
var content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ODataResponse<Person>>();
```

Where ODataResponse is:

```
internal class ODataResponse<T>
{
    public T[] Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the `@odata.xxx` fields in the response JSON (such as implementing a loop for paged results), the following is my implementation which expands on the solution from andygjp.

I'm using [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/) as my HTTP client and [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for (de)serialization. Steps as follows.

Implement a custom `IRestSerializer` that uses Json.NET to replace the default RestSharp serializer. Below example implementation:

```
public class JsonNetSerializer : IRestSerializer
{
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _settings;

    public JsonNetSerializer()
    {
        _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };
        _settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    }

    public string Serialize(Parameter parameter) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameter.Value, Formatting.None, _settings);

    public string Serialize(object obj) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None, _settings);

    public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);

    public string[] SupportedContentTypes => new string[] { "application/json", "text/json", "text/x-json", "text/javascript", "*+json" };

    public DataFormat DataFormat => DataFormat.Json;

    public string ContentType { get; set; } = "application/json";
}
```

Next, define a class that will represent your OData responses. My expanded response class - which includes the `@odata.nextLink` field - looks as follows.

```
private class ODataResponse<T>
{
    public T[] Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@odata.nextLink")]
    public string NextLink { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, I create an instance of `RestClient`, setting up the custom serializer previously created:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://base.url.here/")
    .UseSerializer(() => new JsonNetSerializer());
```

Now when I execute my request, the data in the response object object also contains my OData values.

```
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request);
var nextLink = response.Data.NextLink;
```

I'm sure this can be done using the standard `HttpClient` instead of RestSharp, as the real work is done by the serializer. This was just the example implementation I had on hand.